# MarshalByRefObject Lifetime

Tags: c#, vb.net, remoting, appdomain, object-lifetime

I have a .net WinForms application that loads plugins (dlls) into their own AppDomains, each dll gets its own AppDomain using domain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(). All i want is, that these objects remain connected forever (till the application stops).
The InitialLeaseTime is 5 minutes, but i can't find a way to change that.  ..
I tried overriding InitializeLifetimeService() of the remote object:

```
Public Overrides Function InitializeLifetimeService() As Object  
     Return Nothing  
End Function
```

Here I get a Typeload-Exception, saying that this would break the inheritance rules.
Adding

```
<SecurityPermissionAttribute(SecurityAction.Demand, Flags:=SecurityPermissionFlag.Infrastructure)>
<SecuritySafeCritical>
```

doesn't change anything.

Then:

```
Dim tmpObj As Object = domain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(type.AssemblyName, type.TypeName)
Dim tmpRemote As tmpRemoteType = CType(tmpObj, tmpRemoteType)

Dim lifetimeService As Object = Runtime.Remoting.RemotingServices.GetLifetimeService(tmpRemote)
Dim lease As ILease = TryCast(lifetimeService, ILease)
If (lease IsNot Nothing) Then
     lease.Register(_sponsor)
 End If
```

Doesn't do it neither, because somehow the Renewal() method of the sponsor (not shown here) is never called.

Calling

```
lease.Renew(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(300))
```

directly changes the CurrentLeaseTime but not the InitialLeaseTime of the lease.

Finally i tried calling the shared (static) property LeaseTime, which actually led to a change of CurrentLeaseTime at the beginning of the Lease, but again **NOT** the InitialLeaseTime, which seems to end after 5 minutes and my remote object being gc'ed:

```
LifetimeServices.RenewOnCallTime = System.TimeSpan.FromMinutes(300)
```

Any help is appreciated,
Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what's going on, but here's how it works

```
var sponsor = new Sponsor();  // manages lifetime of the object in otherDomain
var target = otherDomain.CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap(assemblyFilename, typeFullName) 
    as MarshalByRefObject;

var lease = target.InitializeLifetimeService() as ILease;
lease.Register(sponsor);
```

In this case, it is only important that you retain references to *target* (obvious) and *sponsor*.  Sponsor is a class that manages the subscription:

```
class Sponsor : MarshalByRefObject, ISponsor
{
    public bool Release { get; set; }

    public TimeSpan Renewal(ILease lease)
    {
        // if any of these cases is true
        if (lease == null || lease.CurrentState != LeaseState.Renewing || Release)
            return TimeSpan.Zero; // don't renew
        return TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1); // renew for a second, or however long u want
    }
}
```

When you're done with it, simply set Release to `true` on the sponsor and let it go.  You could also do this by implementing IDisposable on Sponsor to handle this, if that tickles your fancy.

Comment: Hi and thanks! With your solution the Renewal() method of the sponsor is called now.But when I return TimeSpan.FromHours(1) sometimes it will work and sometimes not. I've experimented a lot now, but can't figure it out ...btw: lease.CurrentState is always "active" within renewal(), not "Renewing" .

Comment: Update: It's working now. I had references of other objects within my remote object, that also inherited from MarshalByRefObject. The lease of these objects also had to be renewed.